# Exchange Web Services - acknowledging meeting request response

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm working on an application that handles streaming notifications from Exchange Web Services and makes database updates based on those notifications.  I'm monitoring a few calendar folders and tracking changes to the appointments as well as to the attendees. This all works just fine except for one piece.

When someone accepts a meeting request, that acceptance is sent via email.  However, the calendar item is only updated after the user opens the email in Outlook, which presumably causes some behind-the-scenes sync to occur.  If the user does not open the "accepted" or "declined" email, the appointment does not get updated.  This holds true whether I am accessing the appointment via Outlook or via EWS.  Simply marking the email as read via EWS doesn't trigger the sync.  Does anyone know a way to make that sync between the inbox and the calendar happen via EWS without the user having to touch Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the issue turned out to be that the Exchange mailbox itself was not set up to automatically acknowledge responses to meeting requests. There is a mailbox level setting in Exchange that controls this behavior. If it's not set, then there is no way through EWS to force Exchange to acknowledge the response.